# Delete a duplicate record before placing into Android SQLite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am trying to replace a duplicate record I am getting back in the web service call. I have saved the data to the database and trying to do a db.replace. I am getting the error java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.replace(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues)' on a null object reference.

I am not sure why I am getting null, when I debug and go through the points the employeeNumber is populated correctly. So shouldn't it create the record, go to the next one and so forth until it sees that same employeeNumber and then delete the next one?

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private ListView mTopList, directReportListView;
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
private ArrayList<Employee> mEmployees = new ArrayList<>();
private BottomListViewAdapter mBottomListViewAdapter;
EmployeeDBHandler dbHandler;
SQLiteDatabase db;
SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter;
private String startingEmployeeID = employeNumberToRemove;
private String table = "employees";
private static final String KEY_ID = "Employee_number";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    dbHandler = new EmployeeDBHandler(getApplicationContext());

    directReportListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mDirectReportList);
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mBottomListViewAdapter = new BottomListViewAdapter(this, mEmployees);
    directReportListView.setAdapter(mBottomListViewAdapter);
    getBottomViewXMLData();

   // displayTopList(startingEmployeeID);

    //displayTopList();


    //GUI for seeing android SQLite Database in Chrome Dev Tools
    Stetho.InitializerBuilder inBuilder = Stetho.newInitializerBuilder(this);
    inBuilder.enableWebKitInspector(Stetho.defaultInspectorModulesProvider(this));
    Stetho.Initializer in = inBuilder.build();
    Stetho.initialize(in);


}

public void getBottomViewXMLData() {
    OkHttpClient client = getUnsafeOkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(getString(R.string.API_FULL_URL))
            .build();
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
            final String responseData = response.body().string();
            final InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseData.getBytes());
            final XMLPullParserHandler parserHandler = new XMLPullParserHandler();
            final ArrayList<Employee> employees = (ArrayList<Employee>) parserHandler.parse(stream);

            for (Employee e : employees) {
                /*String table = "employees";
                String whereClause = "Employee_number=?";
                String[] whereArgs  = new String[] {String.valueOf(startingEmployeeID)};
                db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
                db.delete(table, whereClause, whereArgs);*/
                dbHandler.addEmployee(e);
                ContentValues mContentValues = new ContentValues();
                mContentValues.put(KEY_ID, startingEmployeeID);
                db.replace(table, "Employee_number", mContentValues);
            }

            mEmployees.clear();
            mEmployees.addAll(employees);

            //tell adapter on the UI thread its data changed
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mBottomListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    directReportListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

public void displayTopList(String employeeNumber) {
    String table = "employees";
    String whereClause = "Employee_number=?";
    String[] whereArgs  = new String[] {String.valueOf(employeeNumber)};
    db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(table, whereClause, whereArgs);
  //  Cursor cursor = (Cursor) dbHandler.getEmployee(startingEmployeeID);
 //   Log.i("ADAM", cursor.toString());
}
```

}

```
public class EmployeeDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "OneTeam";
    private static final String TABLE_EMPLOYEE = "employees";

    //Employee table columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "Employee_number";
    private static final String KEY_FIRST_NAME = "First_name";
    private static final String KEY_LAST_NAME = "Last_name";
    private static final String KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE = "Phone_mobile";
    private static final String KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE = "Phone_office";
    private static final String KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE = "Payroll_title";
    private static final String KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS = "Has_direct_reports";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "Email";
    private static final String KEY_COST_CENTER = "Cost_center_id";
    private static final String KEY_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE = "ThumbnailData";


    public EmployeeDBHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_EMPLOYEE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_EMPLOYEE + "("
                + KEY_ID + " STRING PRIMARY KEY,"
                + KEY_FIRST_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_LAST_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_COST_CENTER + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_EMPLOYEE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //drop old table if existence
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_EMPLOYEE);

        //Create table again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    //Add new employee
    public boolean addEmployee(Employee employee) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ID, employee.getEmployee_number());
        values.put(KEY_FIRST_NAME, employee.getFirst_name());
        values.put(KEY_LAST_NAME, employee.getLast_name());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE, employee.getPhone_mobile());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE, employee.getPhone_office());
        values.put(KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS, employee.getHas_direct_reports());
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, employee.getEmail());
        values.put(KEY_COST_CENTER, employee.getCost_center_id());
        values.put(KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE, employee.getPayroll_title());
        values.put(KEY_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE, employee.getThumbnailData());


        //Inserting Row
        database.insert(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, null, values);
        database.close();
        return true;
    }

    //Get single employee
    public Employee getEmployee(int employeeNumber) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Employee employee = null;

        Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, new String[] {
                KEY_ID, KEY_FIRST_NAME, KEY_LAST_NAME, KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE, KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE,
                KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_COST_CENTER, KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE, KEY_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE}, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{ String.valueOf(employeeNumber)}, null, null, null, null);
        if(cursor != null) {
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                employee = new Employee(cursor.getString(0),
                        cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4),
                        cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(8),
                        cursor.getString(9), cursor.getString(10), cursor.getString(11), cursor.getString(12),
                        cursor.getString(12), cursor.getString(14), cursor.getString(15), cursor.getString(16),
                        cursor.getString(17), cursor.getString(18), cursor.getString(19), cursor.getString(20),
                        cursor.getString(21), cursor.getString(22), cursor.getString(23), cursor.getString(24),
                        cursor.getString(24), cursor.getString(25), cursor.getString(26));
            }
        }
            cursor.close();
            database.close();
            return employee;

    }

    //Get All Employees
    public ArrayList<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        ArrayList<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
        //Select all query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_EMPLOYEE;

        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor =  database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        //looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Employee employee = new Employee();
                employee.setEmployee_number(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
                employee.setFirst_name(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_FIRST_NAME)));
                employee.setLast_name(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_LAST_NAME)));
                employee.setPhone_office(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE)));
                employee.setPhone_mobile(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE)));
                employee.setHas_direct_reports(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS)));
                employee.setEmail(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_EMAIL)));
                employee.setCost_center_id(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_COST_CENTER)));
                employee.setPayroll_title(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE)));
                employee.setThumbnailData(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE)));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        //return employees list
        return employeeList;
    }

    //Get Employee Count
    public int getEmployeeCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_EMPLOYEE;
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        return cursor.getCount();
    }

    //Updating single employee
    public int updateEmployee(Employee employee){
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_FIRST_NAME, employee.getFirst_name());
        values.put(KEY_LAST_NAME, employee.getLast_name());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE, employee.getPhone_mobile());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE, employee.getPhone_office());
        values.put(KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS, employee.getHas_direct_reports());
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, employee.getEmail());
        values.put(KEY_COST_CENTER, employee.getCost_center_id());
        values.put(KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE, employee.getPayroll_title());
        values.put(KEY_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE, employee.getThumbnailData());

        return database.update(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] {String.valueOf(employee.getEmployee_number())});
    }

    //Delete single employee
    public void deleteEmployee(Employee employee) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        database.delete(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] {String.valueOf(employee.getEmployee_number())});
        database.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use database.replace() method instead of database.insert().

Please check [sqliteDatabase.replace()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#replace(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues))

It will internally check,based upon your primary key whether any previous row is present? if Yes then it will update the same row or No then it will insert the new one.

```
public boolean addEmployee(Employee employee) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_ID, employee.getEmployee_number());
    values.put(KEY_FIRST_NAME, employee.getFirst_name());
    values.put(KEY_LAST_NAME, employee.getLast_name());
    values.put(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE, employee.getPhone_mobile());
    values.put(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE, employee.getPhone_office());
    values.put(KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS, employee.getHas_direct_reports());
    values.put(KEY_EMAIL, employee.getEmail());
    values.put(KEY_COST_CENTER, employee.getCost_center_id());
    values.put(KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE, employee.getPayroll_title());
    values.put(KEY_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE, employee.getThumbnailData());


    //Inserting Row
    database.replace(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, null, values);
    database.close();
    return true;
}
```

Update your add employee method to above

```
for (Employee e : employees) {

      dbHandler.addEmployee(e);

 }
```

And for loop from activity to this

Comment: So don't do the dbHandler.addEmployee(e)? I need to make a replace method into the the DatabaseHandler? This is my first time using SQL or SQLite.

Comment: updated my question with the .replace method but still running into an issue

Comment: Remove dbHandler.addEmployee(e)

Comment: With that removed, I still get the same error. Now I am confused on it is looping through the data to populate the database without the .addEmployee method.

Comment: Can you post addEmploee method

Comment: I have added my DatabaseHandler class that has the addEmployee method

Comment: Thank you, that has worked and I accept your answer.